# Vectorial equation of a cone

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

I have this practice exercise that I'm stuck on, where I must find the equation of a cone with its vertex on point $(1,1,1)$ and with its base being the circumference centered on point $(1,1,0)$, enclosed on the $z=0$ plane and with radius $r=1$.

---

I know that the cone surface set is derived by the cylinder:

$$\left\{\boldsymbol{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n:\|\boldsymbol{x}-(\boldsymbol{x}\cdot\boldsymbol{u})\boldsymbol{u}\|=\alpha|\boldsymbol{x}\cdot \boldsymbol{u}|\right\}$$

Where $\boldsymbol{x}=(x,y,z)$, $\boldsymbol{u}$ is the unit vector of the cone axis and $\alpha$ is a constant.

---

**What I've done so far:**

Given that this cone is the similar to the one with vertex on the origin $(0,0,0)$, but moved to the point $(1,1,1)$, I started by defining that cone, with $\boldsymbol{u}=(0,0,1)$ and $\alpha=-1$:

$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=-|z|$$

---

**My questions:**

- I chose $\alpha=-1$ because I was plotting in an online 3d plotter and that was the value that made the cone have the right orientation and have a circular base of radius 1 on $z=-1$ (when we move the vertex to $(1,1,1)$, that base will be centered on $(1,1,0)$) . How to derive this value analytically?
- I don't understand what the effect of the absolute value of $\boldsymbol{x}\cdot\boldsymbol{u}$ is.
- How to "slice" the cone for the base to be of radius 1 (i.e., how to apply the limitation that $x^2+y^2\leq1$ to the surface set?)
- Lastly, how to move the whole thing? Playing with an online 3d plotter, I found that moving the cone vertex from $\boldsymbol{x_0}=(0,0,0)$ to $\boldsymbol{x_1}=(1,1,1)$, we subtract $\boldsymbol{x_0}$ and $\boldsymbol{x_1}$. What's the reason for this? I'm really not seeing.

---

Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

A (half-) cone with vertex $p$, axis in the direction of the unit vector $u$, and angle $\phi$ is given by the equation
$$\frac{x-p}{\|x-p\|}\cdot u = \cos\phi.$$
This comes just from the usual interpretation of the dot product in terms of lengths and angle.

All you have to do with your question is use elementary geometry to deduce $\phi$ and note that $u = (0,0,-1)$.

I have no idea what your "derived by the cylinder" equation is.

Comment: My textbook defines the cylinder which axis is the line that goes through $\boldsymbol{0}$ and the unit vector $\boldsymbol{u}$, and has radius $c$, as this equation: $\|\boldsymbol{x}-(\boldsymbol{x}\cdot\boldsymbol{u})\boldsymbol{u}\|=c$ (i.e., a surface where $\boldsymbol{x}-(\boldsymbol{x}\cdot\boldsymbol{u})\boldsymbol{u}$ is constant). When it is not constant, but proportional to $|\boldsymbol{x}\cdot \boldsymbol{u}|$, the resulting surface will be a cone. I thought that I could solve the problem using only that equation. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yes, in this equation $c$ will be $\tan\phi$. Both equations are based on saying that a cone comes from saying the angle $\phi$ between the axis and the vector $x-p$ is constant.